# How to deploy macchiato clojurescript app to Heroku free account?

Tags: node.js, heroku, clojure, clojurescript

I tried to create blank app of Macchiato (ClojureScript template) by this commands:

```
lein new macchiato abc
cd abc
git init
heroku create
git add --all
git commit -m "Initial"
git push heroku master
heroku run lein package
```

But app crashed.

What I should do to run Macchiato/ClojureScript blank app on free Heroku?

Some logs from Heroku:

```
2017-09-20T14:20:18.982364+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node target/release/abc.js`
2017-09-20T14:20:21.393478+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2017-09-20T14:20:23.735706+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO [abc.core:19] - abc started on 127.0.0.1 : 46297
2017-09-20T14:21:19.612740+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2017-09-20T14:21:19.612805+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2017-09-20T14:21:19.765958+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-09-20T14:21:19.754144+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2017-09-20T14:21:20.199389+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=calm-sea-65041.herokuapp.com request_id=538fbec8-6d9a-4a9c-8ee6-682d2ae18ee4 fwd="194.186.207.221" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-09-20T14:21:20.932872+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=calm-sea-65041.herokuapp.com request_id=74269aea-639d-41b8-8c76-4bb0494eb593 fwd="194.186.207.221" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-09-20T14:21:22.963835+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=calm-sea-65041.herokuapp.com request_id=08a421a1-03a0-4e27-8efe-e4209e249e9a fwd="194.186.207.221" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: why did you run `heroku run lein package`? I think you may want to instead set `heroku config:set LEIN_BUILD_TASK="package"` and then run `git push heroku master`.

Comment: I use this command to build package at Heroku side.

Comment: Tried "heroku config:set LEIN_BUILD_TASK="package"". Not working. Can you reproduce this step-by-step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the source of the problem

```
2017-09-20T14:20:23.735706+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO [abc.core:19] - abc started on 127.0.0.1 : 46297
```

The application only listened to 127.0.0.1, however, heroku expect your app listen on 0.0.0.0.

Add a environment variable `HOST` and the value is `0.0.0.0` should solve the issue.

Comment: Yes, this solves the issue, but also needs to change Procfile. And no need to commit project.clj, becouse Heroku determines project as Clojure, but not Node.js.